# How to change sequence format in my alignment file?

Tags: sequence-alignment, sequence-analysis

I have fasta file with alingned several sequences (from MUSCLE), when I open it (e.g. notepad++) they look like:
[image]

And I want dot format of identities like [image] and then save it in txt file.

I failed using MEGA, BioEdit, Jalview and CodonCode, how can I do this?

Comment: Hi ... this is definitely in MEGA. Could you check again? Try updating to MEGA X?

Comment: @Michael yes I tried. Export to xls and xlsx - crashed. Csv - fine, but only first 1000nt. Unfortunately I have about 40 sequences ~25kb length each. MEGA can't handle this amount of data.

Comment: okay, it must be done because it is very easy to code e.g. via AlignIO in Biopython ... you'll need to adapt it, but all you are doing is splicing through an alignment.